# Netbeans 16 only wants to use subversion but the project directory has been added to .init

Tags: git, netbeans

The title says it all.  When I try to commit a file, it pops up this dialog:
[image]

If I try to reinitialize the project folder, I get this dialog:
[image]

If I navigate to the same folder in my command window and run git commit, it sees the files that have been added.  Git is part of the Base IDE as far as I can see, so its shouldn't be an issue with a missing plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I disconnected from Subversion (must have accidently connected at some point):
Team->Disconnect

It is back to working with git.